# Applescript (or automator action) to convert HTML to Plain Text

Tags: applescript

I had an Applescript or Automator action that let me select files and then it would convert the ones that were HTML to plain text. Somehow I may have lost that script.

I think the script was the one below, but when I use it and select some files, it converts some of them to .rtf and then they disappear. Bizarre.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
set ASTID to AppleScript's text item delimiters

choose file with multiple selections allowed without invisibles
repeat with thisFile in result
    try
        set thisFile to POSIX path of thisFile

        do shell script "/usr/bin/textutil -convert rtf " & quoted form of result

        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {"."}
        set thisFile to text items 1 through -2 of thisFile
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {""}
        set thisFile to thisFile as text

        do shell script "/System/Library/Printers/Libraries/convert" & ¬
            " -f " & quoted form of (result & ".rtf") & ¬
            " -o " & quoted form of (result & ".pdf") & ¬
            "; /bin/rm -f " & quoted form of (result & ".rtf")
    on error errorMsg number errorNum
        display dialog "Error (" & errorNum & "):" & return & return & errorMsg buttons "Cancel" default button 1 with icon caution
    end try
end repeat
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ASTID
```

Comment: I guess it stops once you have error. In this case I think the Display Dialog "Error..." changes the value of global variable Result, and it may affect the main repeat loop which takes thisFile in Result (the same variable). Not ? Except that, I can't test your script because I have no "/System/Library/Printers/Libraries/convert"

Comment: I think you are correct, as I found out I don't have that darn library either....